# Dagger - class has no injectable members

Tags: android, dagger

I'm trying to integrate Dagger into my application. And I ran into a problem. I'm getting this error at runtime:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors creating object graph:
    com.app.NavigationController has no injectable members. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by class com.app.fragments.LoginFragment
```

I tried looking into other, similar answers, but nothing helped me so far...

Everything related to graph construction is implemented pretty much like in [Android Activity Graphs](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs) example.

I have two modules `ActivityModule` and `ApplicationModule`.

```
@Module(
        includes = ApplicationModule.class,
        injects = {
                MainActivity.class,
                LoginFragment.class
        }
)
public class ActivityModule {

    private BaseActivity activity;

    public ActivityModule(BaseActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    NavigationController provideNavigation() {
        return new NavigationController(activity);
    }
}
```

And another

```
@Module(
    injects = {
            MainActivity.class,
            LoginFragment.class},
    complete = false
)
public class ApplicationModule {

    private Context context;

    public ApplicationModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ApiService provideApiService() {
        ....
        return restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Adding more details:

Fragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends BaseFragment {

    //...

    @Inject
    NavigationController navigation;

    //...
```

Navigation controller:

```
public class NavigationController {

//...

public NavigationController(BaseActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

//...
}
```

Comment: Do you have `@Inject` annotated member in `LoginFragment`?

Comment: Yes I do. I've updated my question.

Comment: what if you just remove `injects` section in incomplete module

Comment: Tried that. It does not help. I tried different variations of injects/complete/library but it still fails at runtime.

Comment: I don't know why but `Dagger` is trying to inject `NavigationController` class. Could you remove for in competed module everything and keep only @Module annotation

Comment: Dummy comment, just ignore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question was answered in this Dagger [GitHub issue #372](https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/372)