# Passing parameter from Module to Module

Tags: android, dagger

Using Dagger, for simple things just works pretty good, but i do not understand the rules when i comes when passing Arguments to Modules. Basicly is want to pass the Application Context to the provider Method with creates an Volles Request queue which need the Context.

I create my Modules like this:

```
public static Object[] getModules(@ApplicationContext final Context appContext)
{
    return new Object[]{new ApplicationContextModule(appContext),new ReleaseModules()};
}
```

Application Context Module:

```
@Module(library = true, includes = RequestQueueModule.class)
public final class ApplicationContextModule
{
    private final Context applicationContext;

    public ApplicationContextModule(final Context aContext)
    {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(aContext, "Application Context");
    //
    applicationContext = aContext;
    }

    @ApplicationContext
    @Provides
    //@Singleton
    public Context provideApplicationContext()
    {
    return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

RequestQueueModule:

```
@Module(injects = {AutoCacheService.class, ServiceListFragment.class})
public class RequestQueueModule
{

    //private final Context context;

    //@Inject
    public RequestQueueModule()
    {
    //context = theContext;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public com.android.volley.RequestQueue provideRequestQueue(@ApplicationContext final Context context)
    {
    return Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }
}
```

As you can see i played a bit with Constructor Injection, looks like i miss understood this first. Anyway using the @ApplicationContext Annotation to clarify that the App Context should be injected. But i get this compile error:

> error: @com.app.android.annotation.ApplicationContext()/android.content.Context required by provideRequestQueue(android.content.Context) for com.app.android.application.modules.RequestQueueModule
>           error: No injectable members on com.android.volley.RequestQueue. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by com.app.android.io.service.AutoCacheService for com.app.android.application.modules.ReleaseModules

I spent several hours with this Problem. But can't really see the problem. I also try to avoid the library = true switch when possible, as my understanding it disables the Graph checking during compile time. Some Recipe would be fine to understand this better ...

UPDATE: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932725/dagger-class-has-no-injectable-members) SO Question is similar to mine.

Comment: You should set `complete = false` (and possibly `library = true`) on `RequestQueueModule`.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Update RequestModule like this:

```
@Module(injects = {AutoCacheService.class, ServiceListFragment.class}, addsTo = ApplicationContextModule.class)
public class RequestQueueModule
{
}
```

This is telling Dagger that RequestQueueModule adds the to ApplicationContextModule and has access to dependencies provided in that module. This has the added advantage of giving you compile time validation.

This statement will create the full graph:

```
ObjectGraph graph = ObjectGraph.create(new ApplicationContextModule(), new RequestQueueModule())
```

Alternatively, you can have `complete = false` on the RequestQueueModule, but that will push any errors that can be caught at compile time to runtime instead.